# How to embedd one function into another one in R

Tags: r

I would like to build a function that works similarly to the built-in `pairs()` function. Given the data set `df`, I would like to create a matrix of scatter plots between the numeric class columns of the data set, such that on the diagonal I can get the histogram of those columns including a density function. I have precisely an issue in integrating the diagonal part of the plots. Without the diagonal part of the code, everything works fine (one can test this on the `iris` data set).

```
new_pairs<-function(df, x){
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
n_col<-sum(sapply(df, is.numeric))
par(mfrow=c(n_col,n_col))
n<-ncol(df)
for (i in 1:n){

for (j in 1:n){
  
  if ((class(df[,i])!="factor" ) & (class(df[,j])!="factor") & i!=j)
  {plot(df[,i], df[,j], col = df[,x])}
  
  else if ((class(df[,i])!="factor") & (class(df[,j])!="factor") & i==j)
  {hist(df[,i], breaks=10, probability=T, main=NULL)} {lines(density(df[,i]))}
      }
    }
  }
 new_pairs(df,2)
```

It seems that including the line `{lines(density(df[,i]))}` is not permissible. I get an error message. I therefore tried to build a density function, which will account for missing values. It works fine on a given (numeric class) column but I do not know how to integrate it inside the `new_pairs()` function. Here is the density function:

```
hist_density = function (df[,3]) {
N = length(df[,3])
df[,3] <- na.omit(df[,3])
hist( df[,3], col = "light blue",
    probability = TRUE, main=NULL)
lines(density(df[,3]), col = "red", lwd = 3)
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I corrected it.

Comment: It modulates the color of the data points inside the scatter plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be we can use the `lines` in each of the options

```
new_pairs<-function(df, x){
  par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
   n_col<-sum(sapply(df, is.numeric))
   par(mfrow=c(n_col,n_col))
   n<-ncol(df)
   for (i in 1:n){

     for (j in 1:n){
  
    if ((class(df[,i])!="factor" ) & (class(df[,j])!="factor") & i!=j) {
       plot(df[,i], df[,j], col = df[,x])
         lines(density(na.omit(df[, i])))
  
    }else if ((class(df[,i])!="factor") & (class(df[,j])!="factor") & i==j) {
          hist(df[,i], breaks=10, probability=T, main=NULL)
              lines(density(na.omit(df[,i])))
     } else{ 
          NA
        
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  
new_pairs(iris, 3)
```

---

The `hist` part can be called from a different function created

```
hist_density <- function (df, i) {
   N <- length(df[,i])
  tmp <- na.omit(df[,i])
  hist(tmp, col = "light blue",
    probability = TRUE, main=NULL)
    lines(density(tmp), col = "red", lwd = 3)
}



new_pairs<-function(df, x){
  par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
   n_col<-sum(sapply(df, is.numeric))
   par(mfrow=c(n_col,n_col))
   n<-ncol(df)
   for (i in 1:n){

     for (j in 1:n){
  
       if ((class(df[,i])!="factor" ) & (class(df[,j])!="factor") & i!=j) {
       plot(df[,i], df[,j], col = df[,x])
         lines(density(na.omit(df[, i])))
  
      }else if ((class(df[,i])!="factor") & (class(df[,j])!="factor") & i==j) {
            hist_density(df, i)
       } else {
          NA}
       
         }
        }
       }
     
 new_pairs(iris, 3)
```

Comment: Why did you include `else{ NA }` ?

Comment: @user249018 you have if/else if and no else.  So, I have to fill something with `else`  You may change that to any other plot i.e. `plot(1, 1)` or so

Comment: I have no problem with missing values anymore. When I run the  `lines(density(df[,i]))` alone on a certain column containing missing values, I get an error message, but there is no error message now that it is included inside the `new_pairs()` function. Since omitting the `else{NA}` is not changing anything in the output, I am wondering how did the problem of missing values disappeared ?

Comment: @user249018 You could omit the `else` as well, but as a function with a condition that begins at `if`, it is better to end by including `else`

Comment: @user249018 Also, if you want to the `lines(density(df[,i]))` to be written only once, then have to self contain the conditional statements in a block and execute it

Comment: Yes, right. Do you have any idea how the missing value problem disappeared ?

Comment: @user249018 is it based on the `iris` data (or a different one)

Comment: It is based on another data set, in which almost all columns contain missing values as opposed to the `iris` data.

Comment: @user249018 the `density` requires non-NA elements.  You may need to wrap with` density(na.omit(df[,i]))

Comment: @user249018 can you test the updated code

Comment: Yes. Your suggestion of using `density(na.omit(df[,i]))` seemed to be necessary. I was erroneous in stating that it was not necessary. Do you have any idea how one can in general inbed one function into another one in `R` ? In this case, even though your proposal solved the issue I had, is there a way to include the density function that I wrote above into the `new_pairs()` function ?

Comment: @user249018 i would use the `hist_density` as `hist_density <- function(dat, i) {N <- length(dat[,i]);...` instead of `df[,3]` and then you use that function as `else_if(....) {hist_density(df, i)}`

Comment: @user249018 I updated the post.  Please check it

Comment: I posted an other question, similar to this one, but very important to me. I can not go further. Can you have a look at it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With the danger of being superflous, but without inventing a new method you could use `pairs` itself and simply use the `diag.panel` argument to add the density and histogram yourself. The code below is taken from an example in `help(pairs)` (where I've added the density)

This might be a cleaner solution

```
# Add histograms + density (taken from help("pairs"))
panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
  h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
  breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
  y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
  rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col = "cyan", ...)
  # density
  dens <- density(x); dens$y <- dens$y / max(dens$y)
  lines(dens)
}
pairs(iris[, 1:4], diag.panel = panel.hist)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It looks ok. I wanted to rather write a function. But do you have any idea how to inbed a function into another one ? In this case, the density function into the `new_pairs()` one ?